# Word2vec C++ training on German wikipedia

Tags: c, word2vec

I am using the C version of word2vec (as found at https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) and training it on a filtered dump of the German version of Wikipedia (~17 GB raw text, ~1.4 B words). I am using the following settings:

`-cbow 1 -size 300 -window 5 -negative 25 -hs 0 -sample 1e-4 -threads 20 -binary 1 -iter 15 -min-count 1000`

The resulting output file contains ~50k words, however none of them contain the letters ä, ö, ü or ß. I verified that word2vec can handle them by making a small corpus containing words with those letters and they appeared in the output.

What could be causing the words containing these character to not appear in the output file? Is it somehow related to the large size of the corpus or any of the settings that I am using?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be related to the size of the corpus. I've trained a German model (see link below) with similar settings on a Wikipedia dump and German news articles (600k words in the vocabulary) and generated word vectors for words with German umlauts as well.

Things you can do:

- Check the character encoding of your corpus file as well as your training environment to be UTF-8
- Avoid this problem by converting the umlauts to their respective bigram tokens (ä → ae, ß → ss etc.) in the preprocessing
- Check out [this project](http://devmount.github.io/GermanWordEmbeddings/) where word2vec was applied on a german corpus (but with gensim using the C implementation)